# There is a way to rotate SVG and / or it's VIEBOX?

Tags: javascript, svg, transformation

I'm wondering if there is a way to Rotate SVG (not its elements) or apply a transformation, which has a rotation angle?

Basically what I want to do is to have TWO (probably nested) elements in the screen: container and image, where the image won't be visible out of container boundaries. Kind of Overflow hidden....

Any idea?
Tnx

Comment: Your question really isn't clear. You mention rotation, then clipping. Please provide a better description, possibly with an image to make things clear.

Comment: What does "Rotate SVG element (not its elements) mean"?

Answer (score 0):

Put the svg inside a div or figure then give that a class like rotate, use

```
.rotate {
    transform: rotateZ(50deg);
}
```

in your CSS